# Method of characteristics for generalized transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find a solution to the generalized transport equation $$u_t+4xu_x=0$$ with the initial condition $u(0,x)=\cos(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution. The characteristics are of the form $$\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}(t) = 4x(t),$$whence $$x(t) = Ae^{4t}$$for some $A \in \Bbb R$. Now, we have $$u(t,x) = u(t, Ae^{4t}) = u(0,A) = \cos (A^2),$$since $u$ is constant along the characteristic $(t,Ae^{4t})$ (and we evaluate it at $t =0$). Now, $x = Ae^{4t}$ implies that $A  = xe^{-4t}$, and finally $$u(t,x) = \cos(x^2e^{-8t}).$$

Answer (score 0):

We will use method of characteristics to solve this nonlinear first order PDE. Let $a(t,x)=4x=\dot{x}$ with $x(t_0)=x_0$. From applying variation of parameters formula we have $$\varphi(t)=x_0e^{4(t-t_0)}+\int_{t_0}^{t}e^{4(t-s)}\cdot 0ds$$ the integral drops because there is no function of $t$ in $a(t,x)$ and we are left with $$\varphi(t)=x_0e^{4(t-t_0)}$$ for $t=0$ we have $$\varphi(0)=x_0e^{-4t_0}$$ as a result we can express our solution implicitly to $u_t+a(t,x)u_x=0$ with $u(0,x)=f(x)$ where $u(t,x)=f(xe^{-4t})$. Our $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$ so our solution is $$u(t,x)=\cos(x^2e^{-8t})$$